# Visual studio c# database Error

Tags: c#, sql, csv

i am making a search box in visual studio that looks through a csv file as a database, the sql query works but not fully.
 if i put the sql database as:

```
SELECT Number_Plate, Regstered_Keeper, Make, Model, Year_Of_Make, Colour, Engine_Size, Transmission, Fuel_Type FROM 'tabledata.csv' WHERE Number_Plate = 'B9BOL'
```

it works but only looks through the specific number plate
 but my code is:

```
"SELECT Number_Plate, Regstered_Keeper, Make, Model, Year_Of_Make, Colour, Engine_Size, Transmission, Fuel_Type FROM` `'tabledata.csv' WHERE Number_Plate = "+ textBox1.Text
```

and that does not wok and it displays the following error when excuting:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.
```

in visual studio the code is as follows:

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 Data.Items.Clear();
 var ta = new CarsDataSetTableAdapters.tabledata_csvTa…

Make.DataSource = ta.GetDataByPlate();
 Make.DisplayMember = "Make";
 }
```

Comment: There are back quotes between `FROM` and table name in code sample. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some quotes from around your where clause:

```
"SELECT  Number_Plate, 
         Regstered_Keeper, 
         Make, 
         Model, 
         Year_Of_Make, 
         Colour, 
         Engine_Size, 
         Transmission, 
         Fuel_Type 
FROM     'tabledata.csv' 
WHERE    Number_Plate = '"+ textBox1.Text + "'"
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your response, the problem is still there, i am getting an exeption in the program which states the following


ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.